# SSL Error whilst trying to install matplotlib using pip

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, blender, blender-2.76

I'm trying to install packages using pip3.5 but I am getting the following error:

```
(base) Names-Air:~ name$ pip3.5 install matplotlib
Collecting matplotlib
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/matplotlib/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:720) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlib
(base) Names-Air:~ name$
```

I need to use pip3.5 as I am using it with the blender game engine, which only supports python3.5.3 as far as I know.

Please let me know what I should do to solve this, as all the other solutions I have found to this problem involve upgrading the pip version, which I cannot do.

Comment: Try `pyhon3 -m pip install matplotlib `.

Comment: try adding `--trusted-host pypi.org` flag

source https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5448 by googling pip ssl error

Comment: Both of those suggested solutions just outputted the same error...